# What does "\\[an_IP_address]" do in a run window?

Tags: windows

What does the comand "\\[an_IP_address]" ( (e.g) \\172.16.1.23 ) does when typed in the run window of Windows. When I typed it, it seems to open the Shared folder provided by that IP address(which is also a Windows PC on the network).Sometimes it also requests for a username and password. How is that done? What does it actually do (or) How does it wok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\\ServerNameOrIP\Share` syntax (called [UNC pathing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/967030)) is a Microsoft standard pathing format for Microsoft File and Print Sharing services.

`\\ServerNameOrIP` will show you the root share for that system, and exposes the actual folder/printer shares themselves. It is the same as the command `net view \\ServerNameOrIP` and simply lists the shares.

If the user account that is initiating a connection to the share is not recognized by the computer hosting the share at all, then the user will be asked for credentials. This is common in workgroup environments, where each box must have a similar list of users (with the same passwords) in order to perform sharing operations.

Numerous security settings apply many nuances to share security, so without more info we cannot tell you EXACTLY why any given box prompted you for credentials, but on modern windows systems, the host will require the remote user to be using an account it has some knowledge of, before it will allow shares to be enumerated, which is exactly what browsing the root share is doing.